# Ignoring certain validation rules with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate plugin to do custom validations on my forms.  For one particular type of form, the user has the option to submit the form, or they can also save the form without submitting.  I was able to use `$('form.validate').validate().cancelSubmit = true;` to suppress validation in the onClick handler for the save button, and life was good.

However, one of the custom validations that was written enforces that people must enter legit characters (i.e. it enforces that you use valid ascii characters).  I want to continue to enforce the ascii validation, because if I don't, people are able to save bad data to the database (which subsequently messes up integrations we have running).

Basically I want to enforce all rules except required: true.  I see that you can use the ignore option when setting up the validation on the form `$('form.validate').validate({ignore : ".required"});` but this only seems to work when you are initially setting up the validation.  When I try to do that when a user clicks the button, it doesn't seem to do anything.

I've seen some posts about similar things but usually related to ignoring hidden fields.  Does anybody know the correct syntax / method I need to use to ignore the required rule upon button click?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are methods you can use to dynamically change rules.  You are going to have to show your HTML & jQuery code, and it would be even better with a jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [the `rules('remove')` method to remove your rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules) dynamically.  Something like this on your "save" button.

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    $('#myform').find('.myclass').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('remove', 'required');
    });
    // your code to save form
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/NqT2V/

**Important NOTE**:  [As per `rules('remove')` documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules), *"Manipulates only rules specified via rules-option or via `rules('add')`."*  In other words, this [will not work if your rules are added inline via `class="required"`](http://jsfiddle.net/5bPBZ/).

---

And the [`rules('add')` method to `add` the rules back](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) just before `submit`...

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myform').find('input').each(function () {
        $(this).rules('add', 'required');
    });
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/3G8cN/

Comment: Thanks, Sparky!

I actually had started looking into an answer similar to yours.  I tried to loop through each form element and remove the required rule.  For some reason,

`$(this).rules('remove', 'required');` 

was not working, however 

`$(this).rules('add', { required: false });`

achieved the results I needed.  The required fields' validations get ignored but the ascii validation still works!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MoDiggity, No problem.  See my edits above.  [As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules), `rules('remove')` will not work unless the rule was originally added by the `rules` option within `.validate()` or via the `rules('add')` method.  In other words, `rules('remove')` will not work if the rule was added with a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in the required rule to analize if the element has an in line class 'ignore' declared in the html.

Sample Bellow

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="validate ignore" maxLength="10">
         <label for="userName" class="required">Name</label>    
     </div>   
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $('#userName').rules("add", {
        required: $('#userName').hasClass('ignore')? false: true,
        messages: {
            required: "This field is required!",
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.required:before {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

Before save, Iterate all the items and add the ignore class to the ones you like to bypass. Remove all the ignore class on the ones you like to validate.

Before submit, Iterate all the items and remove the ignore class to the ones you like to be validated.

Side Note: Observe the class="required" at the label. That will add a red asterix aside the field on all the ones that has that class and this is made with the provided css part