# initializing jQuery Validate plugin after form creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to initialize jquery validator on my form after it's been filled in with data from the database, not on page load.

This is because in some cases, I don't want the validator applied at all.  So for those records I don't call the validator initialization.

When I fill the form, the first thing I do is call a "resetEditForm" method:

```
function resetEditForm() {
// REMOVE VALIDATOR
g$("#editESTIPRequestForm").removeData('validator')

// DO SOME MORE FORM RESET THINGS HERE
}
```

Then I fill all the fields in with data.  Then I setup the form display mode (read/only, read/write):

```
function setFormMode(formStatusType) {
    switch (formStatusType) {
        case "ReadOnly":
            // FORM IS IN READ ONLY MODE
            g$('#tabCenter-Data input:not(.needsIDupdate):not(.hasSelect2), #tabCenter-Data textarea:not(.needsIDupdate):not(.hasSelect2)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .hasSelect2').select2("disable");
            // HIDE "REQUIRED" INDICATORS
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .astric').hide();
            // HIDE ALL BUTTONS
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .button').hide();

            break;
        case "ReadWrite":
            // FORM IS IN READ/WRITE MODE
            g$('#tabCenter-Data input:not(.needsIDupdate):not(.hasSelect2), #tabCenter-Data textarea:not(.needsIDupdate):not(.hasSelect2)').removeAttr('disabled');
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .hasSelect2').select2("enable");
            // MAKE "REQUIRED" INDICATORS VISIBLE
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .astric').show();
            // SHOW ALL BUTTONS
            g$('#tabCenter-Data .button').show();

            setupValidator();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is the function that is supposed to initialize the validator on the form:

```
function setupValidator() {

    g$("#editESTIPRequestForm").validate({
        ignore: null,
        errorElement: "span",
        rules: {
            detailsStatus: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsJobType: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsMpoRural: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsResponsiblePartyJurisdiction: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsTipID: {
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsRoute: {
                required: true,
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsLocationRpt: {
                required: true,
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsWorkType: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsTransSystem: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsWorkDescriptionRpt: {
                required: true,
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsTemplate: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsAirQualityConformityRequired: {
                required: true
            },
            detailsEmissionsCO: {
                number: true
            },
            detailsEmissionsCO2: {
                number: true
            },
            detailsEmissionsNox: {
                number: true
            },
            detailsEmissionsVoc: {
                number: true
            },
            detailsEmissionsPM2: {
                number: true
            },
            detailsAuthorComments: {
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsMdotComments: {
                regexAllowedCharacters: true
            },
            detailsLetIndicator: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return (currentUserRole == "ADMN" || currentUserRole == "MDOT");
                }
            },
            detailsNonLetReason: {
                required: function (element) {
                    var selectedLetIndicatorValue = g$("input:radio[name='detailsLetIndicator']:checked").val();
                    return ((currentUserRole == "ADMN" || currentUserRole == "MDOT") && (selectedLetIndicatorValue == "NonLet"));
                }
            },
            detailsScheduledLetDate: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return (currentUserRole == "ADMN" || currentUserRole == "MDOT");
                }
            }
        },
        onsubmit: false,
        errorClass: "invalid",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (g$(element).hasClass("hasSelect2")) {
                //error.appendTo(g$(element).prev());
                error.insertAfter(g$(element).prev("div"));
            } else if (g$(element).is("input:radio")) {
                var groupName = g$(element).attr("name");
                error.insertAfter(g$("input:radio[name=" + groupName + "]:last + label"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(g$(element));
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            var elementToWorkOn = element;
            if (g$(element).hasClass("hasSelect2")) {
                elementToWorkOn = g$(element).prevAll("div");
            } else if (g$(element).is("input:radio")) {
                var groupName = g$(element).attr("name");
                elementToWorkOn = g$("input:radio[name=" + groupName + "]");
            }

            g$(elementToWorkOn).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            var elementToWorkOn = element;
            if (g$(element).hasClass("hasSelect2")) {
                elementToWorkOn = g$(element).prevAll("div");
            }

            g$(elementToWorkOn).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);

            if (this.numberOfInvalids() == 0) {
                g$("#estipFormErrorMessageBox").hide();
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            g$("#estipFormErrorMessageBox").show();
        }
    });
}
```

However, the validation rules are never applied to the form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like they should be applied.  You're going to have to explain more about what _"never applied to the form"_ even means.  You still have to either manually alter form data or hit the submit button before a validate test.  Otherwise, you can manually force a validation test with `g$("#editESTIPRequestForm").valid()` after you've initialized it.

Comment: @Sparky What I mean, is that when I go in and make an element invalid (a required drop down list, for example), it's supposed to show add the invalid class and add the error text next to it.  And it doesn't do that.  It doesn't even fire the "errorPlacement" callback function (I put an alert in there to check).  If I place this within the doc.ready, it applies the validation to the form, but I need it only applied in some situations.

Comment: Are you positive `setupValidator();` is even called?

Comment: yes, I put an alert at the beginning of the function before the validate() and it shows.

Comment: I think your best best would be to initialize it within the `doc.ready` as we already know that works for you (leave out the rules).  Then within your `setFormMode` function, you can add rules as required using the `rules('add')` method.  (This is also the proper way to add rules to dynamically created fields.)

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566837/594235

Comment: Again, think about what I tried to tell you only three comments ago.  Initialize within DOM ready and use the built-in methods to dynamically add and alter the rules as your cases require.

Comment: What is the status of this?  Have you made any progress?  Did you see the demo and try my suggestion yet?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you initialize `.validate()` within a `document.ready`, but without the rules.  Then load the rules, **as needed**, using the [`rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).  Also use `rules('add')` to add your rules to dynamically created `input` fields right after you create them.

[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/BYWAb/)  Click submit button  and nothing happens (no rules).  Then click the "load the rules" button and suddenly form validation will be active on the next applicable event.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BYWAb/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // other options
    });

    //enclose the following block within whatever required to load these rules
    // function setFormMode(formStatusType) { // whatever
    // switch (formStatusType) { // whatever
        ...

        $('.myclass').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            });
        });

    // end block

});
```